# Unix: appending the values to dynamic array for later use

Tags: bash, unix

I have input read from a file and each line in the file will be having fields terminated by '|'. I wanted to loop to an array so that I can use in my later code. This what I have arrived so far, but looping thru array does not work.

```
#!/bin/ksh

TEMP="abc1|abc2|abc3 1;abc4 1"
rest=$TEMP
field=()

while [ -n "$rest" ]
do
        str=${rest%%\|*}
        field+=("$str")
        [ "$rest" = "${rest/\|/}" ] && rest= || rest=${rest#*\|}
        #print $str
done

for x in ${field}
do
        echo $x

done
```

print $str works fine, but when I loop to get the value I don't get the values.
Any help to resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing something...

```
for x in "${field[@]}"; do echo $x; done
```

Comment: that's exactly what he needs to do add `[@]` and quote it as shown.

Comment: Please, explain it or highliht it in the answer... It was marked as too short. (Previous comment deleted).